# how to separate data with Quotations marks in php

Tags: php

I have a variable

```
<?php 
    $srch_key = 'asdfggfdsa' ;
?>
```

Now I want to make a separation with comma after 5 letters. For this I have done this code.

```
<?php
  function ref_format($str, $step, $reverse = false) {
    if ($reverse)
      return strrev(chunk_split(strrev($str), $step, ','));
    return chunk_split($str, $step, ',');
  }
  $passport = ref_format("$srch_key", 5);
  echo $passport_key = substr($passport, 0, -1);
?>
```

The Output seems like this

```
asdfg,gfdsa
```

But I want to make the output like this

```
'asdfg','gfdsa'
```

How can I make this.

Comment: So where are you attempting to add the single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$srch_key = 'asdfggfdsa' ;
$arr = str_split($srch_key, "5");
$res = "'" . implode ( "', '", $arr ) . "'";
echo $res;
```

Comment: What makes this answer better than others? No explanation or nothing, and has some mistakes too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

```
function ref_format($str, $step, $reverse = false)
{
    if ($reverse)
        return strrev("'" . implode("','", str_split($str, $step)) . "'");
    return "'" . implode("','", str_split($str, $step)) . "'";
}
```

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman why are you commenting this on my answer ? And no, your answer was completely wrong (have you checked your output ?), using different functions. Anyway, SO is not a contest, you have 100K+ rep you should be a well behaving user ...

Comment: I was just telling mate... Wasn't it kinda peer forced deletion? That's what I meant. I should have checked the answer once, but yeah, that's my mistake. `:(` I had also added one more point that OP's having an XY problem and no one noticed it. *`why are you commenting this on my answer`* Just wanted to tell you. `:)`